# Can I view the emails of the users who have permissions - SP 2010

Tags: 2010, list, email

I need to see the emails of the users which have permissions to a site. 
There is such option when you are viewing users in a group - Settings -> List Settings. 
I cannot find this for people outside groups.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "Outside" mean? Active directory group?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden List in the Site which lists all Users who has permissions on the site.

URL - `http://siteurl/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx`

If you know the User ID then details can be retrieved using

URL - `http://siteurl/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?id={UserID}&Force=True`